# How to solve array out of bound exception?

Tags: android

This is my code and I am getting array out of bound exception.how I solve this error?I used Bitmap object instead of string .when I store bitmap image into array list I got this error.

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    ListView lv;
    Context context;

    ArrayList prgmName;
    Bitmap bitmap;
    //bitmap=getBitmapFromUrl("http://content6.flixster.com/movie/11/17/75/11177548_pro.jpg");

    public static String [] prgmNameList={"Let Us C","c++","JAVA","Jsp","Microsoft .Net","Android","PHP","Jquery","JavaScript"};
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        bitmap=getBitmapFromUrl("http://content6.flixster.com/movie/11/17/75/11177548_pro.jpg");
        context=this;
        Bitmap  [] prgmImages ={bitmap,bitmap};
        lv=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        lv.setAdapter(new CustomAdapter(this, prgmNameList,prgmImages));

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
    private Bitmap getBitmapFromUrl(String src) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try {

            URL url =new URL(src);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.connect();
            InputStream input=connection.getInputStream();
            Bitmap mybiBitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
            return mybiBitmap;


         } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
           e.printStackTrace();
           return null;
         }


    }

}
```

CustomerAdapter.java

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
    String [] result;
    Context context;
 Bitmap[] imageId;
      private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;
    public CustomAdapter(MainActivity mainActivity, String[] prgmNameList, Bitmap[] prgmImages) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        result=prgmNameList;
        context=mainActivity;
        imageId=prgmImages;
         inflater = ( LayoutInflater )context.
                 getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return result.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    public class Holder
    {
        TextView tv;
        ImageView img;
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Holder holder=new Holder();
        View rowView;        
             rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
             holder.tv=(TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
             holder.img=(ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);       
         holder.tv.setText(result[position]);
         holder.img.setImageBitmap(imageId[position]);         
         rowView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {         
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Toast.makeText(context, "You Clicked "+result[position], Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });  
        return rowView;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You getting ArrayIndexOutOfBound because **imageId** don't have same array size of **result**.

You can see your **result** array has 9 element and **imageId** has only 2 element, and both element are same, then why you using array, Just pass simple bitmap instead of array.

your result array:

```
 public static String [] prgmNameList={"Let Us C","c++","JAVA","Jsp","Microsoft .Net","Android","PHP","Jquery","JavaScript"};
```

your imageId array:

```
 Bitmap  [] prgmImages ={bitmap,bitmap};
```

**Solution :**

1) If you want to display different images for row item then pass **imageId** array same size of 
**result** array.
2) If you want to display same image in all row item then pass only single bitmap instead of array.

Comment: I did changes,if(result != null && result.length > position)
        { 
          holder.tv.setText(result[position]);
        }

        if(imageId != null && imageId.length > 0)
        {
           holder.img.setImageBitmap(imageId[0]); 
        } but images not displayed into list view,how i display image?

Comment: ya error solved but image is still not displayed into list view,why image is not display into list view?how can i solve this problem?

Comment: Bitmap  [] prgmImages ={bitmap,bitmap,bitmap,bitmap,bitmap,bitmap,bitmap,bitmap,bitmap};

Comment: @user3354610 may be bitmap is null.

Comment: public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {Holder holder=new Holder();View rowView;rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);holder.tv=(TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);holder.img=(ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);if(result != null && result.length > position){ holder.tv.setText(result[position]);}if(imageId != null && imageId.length > 0){ holder.img.setImageBitmap(imageId[0]);}

Comment: this is the value i set into bitmapbitmap=getBitmapFromUrl("http://content6.flixster.com/movie/11/17/75/11177548_pro.jpg");private Bitmap getBitmapFromUrl(String src) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  try {
    
      URL url =new URL(src);
      HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();connection.setDoInput(true);connection.connect();InputStream input=connection.getInputStream();Bitmap mybiBitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input); return mybiBitmap;
 } catch (Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();
     return null; }

Comment: private Bitmap getBitmapFromUrl(String src) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  try {
    
      URL url =new URL(src);
      HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
      connection.setDoInput(true);
      connection.connect();
      InputStream input=connection.getInputStream();
      Bitmap mybiBitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
      return mybiBitmap;
      
      
      } catch (Exception e) {
   // TODO: handle exception
     e.printStackTrace();
     return null;
      }
  
  
 }

Answer (score 0):

Your string array has 9 items. So your adapter return 9 in getCount()

```
public static String [] prgmNameList={"Let Us C","c++","JAVA","Jsp","Microsoft .Net","Android","PHP","Jquery","JavaScript"};
```

But your bitmap array has only 2 items

```
Bitmap  [] prgmImages ={bitmap,bitmap};
```

So in `getView` method you will receive out of bound at this line, when listView request creation of third item in list.

```
holder.img.setImageBitmap(imageId[position]);
```

To fix it, you must expand your image array. It size must match size of string array.

Answer (score 0):

in your getView method you have prgmImage array which has size 2 
but pos may have n nos.

try this...

```
   if(result != null && result.length > position)
        { 
          holder.tv.setText(result[position]);
        }

        if(imageId != null && imageId.length > 0)
        {
           holder.img.setImageBitmap(imageId[0]); 
        }
```

It all depends on what count you return from getCount()
if you return 10 and you access 10th element of array (e.g. arr[position]) but array's size mentioned is 2 then it'll throw the exception.